# how to make inner div alignment fixed

Tags: html, jquery, css

I tried to align div with content towards right irrespective of resolution, now as observed when the inner text content increases the position of the whole div is dynamic not fixed.

expectation is content should be fixed and any additional text should should wrap in same div with no changes in div position towards left

**Html:**

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <img src="" style="min-height: 100px;" width="100%">
  <div style='position: absolute; top: 10%; right: 10%;'>
    <h1>text1</h1>
    <div>text2</div>
    <a>link text</a>
  </div>
</div>

 <div style="position: relative">
  <img src="" style="min-height: 100px;" width="100%">
  <div style='position: absolute; top: 10%; right: 10%;'>
    <h1>text1 2 3 4 5 6 </h1>
    <div>text2 3 4 5 6</div>
    <a>link text</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems fixed to me - if it's because the text moves as you add more content, then you would need to give a fixed size to your div too

Comment: The question is unclear as it asks about position fixed, but the code uses position absolute.

Comment: @Pete if i've  multiple div's with different content when we look at the screen alignment looks crazy . updated code snippet pls check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- Wrapper -->
<div style="position: relative;">

  <div style="position: absolute; width: 100px; top: 10%; right: 10%;">
    <div>
      <img src="" style="min-height: 100px;" width="100%">
      <div>
        <h1>text1</h1>
        <div>text2</div>
        <a>link text</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="" style="min-height: 100px;" width="100%">
      <div>
        <h1>text1 2 3 4 5 6 </h1>
        <div>text2 3 4 5 6</div>
        <a>link text</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="" style="min-height: 100px;" width="100%">
      <div>
        <h1>text1 2 3 4 5 6 </h1>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <a>link text</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: each div is a separate component & independent block cant have same parent div

Comment: @supercool  Then, use the html you have and add width to div, it will align

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `text-align` property to end, which will align the contents of the div to its end (right edge in this case) regardless of the length of any of the 3 text elements inside it.

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <img src="" style="min-height: 100px;" width="100%">
  <div style='position: absolute; top: 10%; right: 10%; text-align:end'>
    <h1>text1</h1>
    <div>this is demo text to show alignment towards the end</div>
    <a>link text</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we have fixed alignment at start not at the end, updated Q pls check